# Storage of Halogen

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I learned that we should store Bromine in brown coating glass bottle. But, I heard that halogen liquid is so reactive that it can melt even glass. So, I want to know the practical storage method of halogen.

Comment: Which halogen? Fluorine would eat glass; bromine definitely wouldn't.

Comment: The "halogen liquid that can even melt glass" could be [chlorine trifluoride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorine_trifluoride), which can indeed react with glass and just about every other oxide you can think of.  Fortunately, your bromine is not that stuff.

Comment: What do you mean by "melt"? Melting suggests a phase transition, has little to do with chemistry between whatever halogen you are asking about and the vessel, and is essentially a physical process.

Answer (score 4):

I assume liquid halogen to be bromine. [From here:](https://www.bromaid.org/safetysummary/)

> Glass, ceramic nickel or lead containers are suitable for bromine.
> Lead-lined steel tanks can be used. Only highly fluorinated plastics
> will resist corrosion. A free space of 8-10% by volume should be left
> in the container.

Also see: https://patents.google.com/patent/US3375077

Answer (score 1):

We know now that bromine can be stored safely in glass (with appropriate glass handling, of course).  Now for the "brown" part.

Bromine can break down on exposure to ultraviolet light, a reaction shown [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/66495/bromination-of-hexene-in-presence-of-uv-light-or-heat) as part of an alkene bromination.  Uncontrolled, this process could release reactive atoms; these may degrade surrounding materials and the products then contaminate the bromine and the surroundings.  The brown glass commonly seen in chemical storage bottles is designed to screen out this radiation.